# VPS set up to serve php and rails

Tags: deployment, vps, rails

I have a VPS with centOS that we currently use for serving php apps with apache. Now I also want to serve rails app from there. Either I can use phusion-passenger or I can do a separate unicorn and nginx setup for my rails app. Which way would be better? I have more than 10 php apps and 1 rails app. I also don't want php apps and rails app and servers to be messed up.
And I don't want to invest on a new VPS for single rails app.
Regards

Comment: Have you tried either of these and did you run into any issues? What defines "better" for you?

Comment: I have not tried any of these before that's why I am asking. Better means what's a good approach if I had to serve both PHP and Rails from one VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am more of a fan of the nginx/Unicorn combination (I tried to compare different hosting approaches [here](http://www.relativkreativ.at/articles/4-popular-rails-serving-approaches-performance-compared)).

My server currently runs some small Rails applications (using this stack) and PHP for Piwik analytics stuff.

I have written an ebook which covers setting up a Rails server completely from scratch (using rbenv, nginx, Unicorn and MySQL) and illustrates how to deploy an application manually - the goal is to help readers understand the inner workings of the deployment process.

It should not be too hard to use the steps from the book with Apache instead of nginx if you do not want to run two webservers in parallel.

It's free for people on my mailing list. If you are interested, you can grab your copy [here](http://www.relativkreativ.at/ebook).